# Can I add google analytic to an email (both html / text version)?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am wondering whether i can add google analytic to an email.
I want to check my click rate , open rate of my sent mail. I have done some research on this and I learnt that there is a  track code should be useful.

So,
Since now i am sending an html version email, is it possible to add the code into the mail?

Also, 
If i want to see the result of it , is it possible i do not need to login to the google page, but connect to their server and retrieve the result and show them on my php page?

Thank you

Comment: And this is why most email clients do not open remote images by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say NO on this question. You could of course add the Google Analytics script-snippet to your HTML email, but I believe most e-mail clients will block the JavaScript for security reasons. Thus leaving you with inaccurate data, at best.

In your case, if you don't want to send your mails through [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) or some other third party service that does the tracking for you (they track both openings and clicks), I would implement my own "simple" tracking system. Each link in the email re-directs through a page that you are in control of, where you track the click and then redirect the user to the appropriate address.

**Update**

About getting data from your Google Analytics account, I believe you can use the [Analytics Reporting API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html). Haven't tried it myself, but it sounds like what you are needing.

Comment: Thank you.So if a mail without link is fine? I can not track the result (eg. click rate ) of the url in the mail content? but i can view how many opened, read the mail?

Comment: @user782104 It is fine to use links in your e-mail, but to be able to track how many clicks each link get, you will have to implement some kind of tracking, where the link goes something like `<a href="http://yourcdomain.com/emaillink=1">Some link text</a>`, that page will then count the click and then redirect the user to the actual page. For tracking e-mail openings, I believe the most common way is to have a 1x1 px image somewhere in your HTML-email, that the client loads, and then you can track how often that image is loaded.

Comment: So how about viewing the result? Can i get it from google server directly (each data) / I can integrate the result (the result such as graph, bar chart, table) / I have to login and view , that is the only way?

Comment: as  Quentin said, the mail client will block the image, so redirect is the best way? but there should be some javascript invloved? Thanks.

Comment: @user782104 If you roll your own e-mail click/open tracking, you will not be able to get the data through Google Analytics - but it is possible to retrieve data tracked by Google Analytics for display elsewhere. See my updated answer.

Comment: @user782104 No need for JavaScript, use a regular `<a>` for the link in your email, then the tracking-page should re-direct the user to the appropriate address.

Comment: that means I need the mail receiver to click on a link before reading the actual message?

Comment: @user782104 Miss-understood your there. For tracking clicks you use regular `<a>`. For tracking email openings you use an `<img>`-tag. That can, as quentin said, be blocked by the email-client, which is a problem. Not sure if there is a fallback solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , when you are sending the HTML code to the client , enclose an analytics snippet in the FOOTER of your page. That should do it. However you cannot modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytics tracking code, but you will see the "visits" only.
"Visits" => When a user opens an email of you (and of course to be connected to internet)

I think this code will not work inside Outlook.

To see the results, you need to login into your Google Analytics account.

PS: Be sure to setup a valid analytics tracking code.

Comment: Besides login in to their page,  i can not have any api to integrate the result into my php page? thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can only track link-clicks with Google Analytics if your target site has the Analytics Code in it:

You can read about it here:
http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/03/tips-for-tracking-email-marketing.html

Comment: Direct links to Files will now work. You will have to create a intermediate HTML Page which has the Google Analytics Script included.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use google analytic's to track open rates.

If you have a pure text version of a email no it is not possible to track it as it need a call to a image so it is only possible using a html version. No you do not try and embed the standard javascript for the tracking you make a direct call to the tracking gif.

There was a free service that did do this

http://web.archive.org/web/20100828084217/http://email-tracking-with-google-analytics.com/index.php